# ImageResizing paddingColor adversely affects white balance

Tags: imageresizer

Is there a way to instruct the ImageResizer to apply white balance BEFORE padding?  The padding appears to be affecting the white balance algorithm.

example:

http://z.zr.io/ri/fix/26s.jpg?width=530&a.balancewhite=true&paddingWidth=8&paddingColor=red
http://z.zr.io/ri/fix/26s.jpg?width=530&a.balancewhite=true&paddingWidth=8&paddingColor=black

notice that the white balance is different, how can I get the white balance calculation to be the same no matter the padding color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [confirmed bug in ImageResizer](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/issues/117). Previously, all AdvancedFilters were applied to the canvas as a whole, instead of just the image region.

It has been [fixed in the develop branch](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/commit/3d46c09e960d1de36ca91245e27781332adfda2b), which targets 4.X releases, and includes behavioral changes like this. Public nightly builds should be available once our CI system is fully online.